# Is the cost of pushing proportional to the array's size?

Tags: solidity

Like above, I've been wondering how array pushes scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no, the cost of pushing doesn't increase with the arrays size.

The slightly longer answer is that you can test this fairly easily on Remix. Use the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Thingy {
    uint[] public thing = [1];


    function addToArray() public {
        thing.push(1);
    }
}
```

Compile/deploy it in the JavaScript VM on Remix, then on the Run tab keep calling addToArray. You can view the Details of each transaction and see that they have a constant gas used per transaction.